# Search for hyphenated terms gives 0 results

Tags: solr

I am unable to retrieve hyphenated terms in my SOLR search results. For example, when I try to do a search like: superman, super man etc., I should see titles like super-man, super-man3 etc. in my search results.

The FieldType is as follows:

```xml
<fieldType name="autocomplete_edge" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:-_])" replacement=" " replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="1" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:-_])" replacement=" " replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(.{30})(.*)?" replacement="$1" replace="all" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: can you please post the fieldtype in more readable format ?

Comment: Hi, the original question is edited to have content in more readable format. Search term like super, super-, super-man, superman return the desired titles. The case where it is failing is: super man which gives 0 results

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) for your use case.

WordDelimiterFilterFactory would allow you to generate tokens that can be split on special characters and numbers and also maintain the Original so that it would match the search terms.

for e.g.
`generateWordParts` would convert `super-man` -> `super, man`
`splitOnNumerics` would generate super-man3 -> `super, man, 3`
`catenateWords` would convert `super-man` -> `superman`
`catenateAll` would convert `super-man3` -> `superman3`

So this would provide you the ability to match the combination of the same words

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are tokenizing your hyphens ok (see WordDelimiterFilterFactory as mentioned in the answer below) then is your default field (df) in your solr config file or passed as a parameter (&df=xxxx) the same as the field you are tokenizing on?

Say your default field is: text
and your indexed field is: name

If we query for super man

```
name:super man
```

The actual query is:

```
parsedquery_toString: "+name:super +text:man"
```

Which won't match. If you query for super man in quotes:

```
name:"super man"
```

it should work fine but is less flexible:

```
parsedquery_toString: "name:\"super man\"",
```

if you set your df to name (e.g. matching the indexed field) it gives:

```
parsedquery_toString: "+name:super +name:man"
```

or you can directly query

```
name:super name:man
```

Note if you are using dismax you may need to look at the mm field if you are still not matching.